# with no errors reported on console, how to determine what part of my JS slows down site over time

Tags: javascript, performance, recursion

To clarify, is there a plugin or extension for web browsers that will tell me more about what areas of code causing things like errant event loops (unintended recursion), or events firing more quickly than they can be processed.

I'm working on a site where although everything "works", continued use and interaction will begin to cause music to play in a 'choppy" manner, and mouse/touch triggered animations or effects to become visibly sluggish. It happens with multiple browsers. (Not all, IE works great for a change!)

In the past I had run into a similar situation where the Firefox console EVENTUALLY reported "too much recursion", halted execution, and even identified the part of the code I needed to look at! Very helpful, but it evidently had to be going on a long time before it became critical. Is there a better tool or cross browser add-on to better monitor, analyze, discover (and hopefully localize) such issues? Perhaps at least a browser setting (in ANY browser) that would warn about recursion after a low number of loops?

Comment: "Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it."

Comment: Have you tried using the profiling tools in Firefox or Chrome?

Comment: The Firefox's Performance tab under Web Developer tools should do the trick.

Comment: @rsm appreciated.

Comment: @Pointy No! I was not aware of this! I have an older version of Chrome, which I believe makes it available as the "Record JavaScript CPU Profile". Having been such a FF toolset fan, I never tried this. Thanks!

Comment: @rodrigoap - I've tried it but likely have not set it up correctly. I'll try again! Thanks.

Comment: sadly, none the performance tools in either my FF or Chrome browser help. Sure, they will record performance and give you a colorful graph, with redder colors showing the hot-spots while your page is performing tasks (playing music, displaying features etc). But these graphs do nothing to clue me as to where in the code, or even what JS file or function is causing the slow down. I.E,. its showing me what i already know. For example, if music is playing and is choppy, the chops tell me of the bad performance spikes too. But no clue as to why, or even why it takes so long to start happening.

Comment: This maybe a  partial solution, I'll trust the guidance of others as to whether I should post it. I recently discovered that global variables (including big objs like HTML5 audio) are retained between short visits due to caching, Even though music may stop when you reload, it apparently can result in a retained object and a new one trying to play the same music (or worse different songs) simultaneously. Of course after garbage collection things settle, but during dev, you tend to reload often. Anyway, a "cleanup" function in the "onunload" event, setting things to 'null', works wonders!